# How can send audio and video files to Telegram via TLSharp in c#?

Tags: c#, telegram

I'm working with TLSharp NuGet in my C# code and I can send photo files via below code:

```
var request = new Message_SendMediaRequest(
new InputPeerContactConstructor(contactId),
new InputMediaUploadedPhotoConstructor(file));
```

but when I try to send audio or video files and I change
             `InputMediaUploadedPhotoConstructor(file) to InputMediaUploadedAudioConstructor(file, duration)` 
I can't do it and I have this error message:
 `"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."`. 
What should I do? Thanks.

Comment: please use proper formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At fisrt I used TLSharp Nuget and Dlls but when I deploy the source code to my project and set IP server and it's port and api id and api hash, my problem to be solved:

```
public async Task<bool> SendAudioMessage(int contactId, InputFile file, int duration)
{
var request = new Message_SendMediaRequest(
new InputPeerContactConstructor(contactId),
new InputMediaUploadedAudioConstructor(file, duration));
await _sender.Send(request);
await _sender.Recieve(request);
return true;
}
```